# Powershell - Add string of text at the beginning of a text file

Tags: powershell, addition, move

I have a directory of text files and would like to add a string of text to the beginning of each file then possibly move the file to another directory once the text has been added. I know how to append text to the end of a file, but not the beginning of a file. I am still fairly new to powershell and scripting in general so treat it like you're talking to an idiot.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is a useful question and answer for me - I'm not sure why it's downvoted. The Add-Content help on MS provides no info for pre-pending data.

Answer (score 6):

At the bare minimum, you might want to do something like this:

```
$Directory="C:\Scripts\Test"
$TextToAdd = "text here, yo"
$NewPath="C:\Scripts\Test\NewPath"
Get-ChildItem $Directory -Filter "*.txt" | foreach {$TextToAdd+"`r`n" + (get-content $_) | Out-File $_;  Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination $NewPath}
```

1. The first part gets all text files in the $Directory
2. The second part iterates through each file, takes the text you want to add and puts it before the content of the current file.
3. The third part replaces the file with the new content. And will then move those to the new destination.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Edit:
This is what you're looking for. Note the added ".FullName" and the "-raw" in Get-Content.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter "*.txt" | foreach {$TextToAdd+"`r`n" + (Get-Content $_.FullName -raw) | Out-File $_.FullName; Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $NewPath}
```

Comment: Thanks for the starting point. I tried what you suggested, but it over-wrote what was in the file with the $TextToAdd. Also for some reason, it looked in the directory that the script was saved in as opposed to the $Directory. I need to add a new line in the beginning of the file. But it was a good starting point and I was able to get what you were trying to do, thank you for the explanation. So I tried the following: 
   `$content = (Get-Content $_)
    Set-Content $_ -value $TextToAdd+"`r`n", $content
    Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination $newpath`
But nothing happens. Help please.

Comment: That's my bad. I edited my answer with the correct code.